# Where to store custom user settings in OOB application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to figure out how to store user settings.

A User goes to `Settings`. There are lists of services and categories etc and the user selects which of them he/she wants to use. These lists are loaded from `.xml` files and have a simple structure, ie `ServiceName + true/false` (selected/not selected). But through the lifetime of the application there will be added another lists so there can be something about 50 .xml files or more.

Is `IsolatedStorageSettings` everything I need or it is only for application settings and preferences and not for custom user settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Application Setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)s stored in Isolated Storage but for what you're trying to do you might want to look at something like [SterlingDB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/).  SterlingDB is simple and it's easy to get up and running.  It also uses Isolated Storage.

Comment: This looks pretty cool! It's a hot candidate to solve my problem. Of course after I finish my SQL to NoSQL mindshift. :-)